# Remove <U+00A0> from values in columns in R

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

When I read my csv file using read.csv and using the encoding parameter, I get some values with  in them.

```
application <- read.csv("application.csv", na.strings = c("N/A","","NA"), encoding = "UTF-8")
```

The dataset looks like

```
           X                                      Y
Met<U+00A0>Expectations               Met<U+00A0>Expectations
Met<U+00A0>Expectations               Met<U+00A0>Expectations
        NA                            Met<U+00A0>Expectations  
Met<U+00A0>Expectations               Exceeded Expectations
Did<U+00A0>Not Meet Expectations      Met<U+00A0>Expectations
Unacceptable                          Exceeded Expectations
```

How can I remove the  from these values? If I do not use the "encoding" parameter, when I show these values in the shiny application, it is seen as:

```
Met<a0>Expectations and Did<a0>Not Meet Expectations
```

I have no clue on how to handle this.

PS: I have modified the original question with examples of the problem faced.

Comment: If it's just a column with extra . in the name you could run something like this to substitute the . with a space `sub("\\."," ",dataframe$column)`

Comment: @Kristofersen: The problem is not with the column names, but with the values in each column. I have edited the post with some more information.

Comment: sorry, the code actually works for the column. Just replace dataframe with whatever your dataframe name is and column with whatever your column name is and all . will be replaced with a space.

Comment: @Kristofersen Sorry I was able to get your point, but I was not clear in asking the question. I have added an example of what the problem is and kept the question simple. When I use "encoding" as a parameter, I get <U+00A0> in some of the values. I am looking to remove these from the dataset.

Answer (score 3):

The problem bores me a long time, and I search all around the R communities, no answer in "r" tag can work in my situation. Until I expanded search area, I got the worked answer in "java" tag.
Okay,for the data frame, the solution is:

```
application <- as.data.frame(lapply(application, function(x) {
              gsub("\u00A0", "", x) 
         }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

```
application <- read.csv("application.csv", na.strings = c("N/A","","NA"), encoding = "ASCII")
```

or with `{readr}`

```
application <- read_csv("application.csv", na.strings = c("N/A","","NA"), locale = locale(encoding = "ASCII"))
```

Converting UTF-8 to ASCII will remove the printed UTF-8 syntax, but the spaces will remain. Beware that if there are extra spaces at the beginning or end of a character string, you may get unwanted unique values. For example `"Met Expectations<U+00A0>"` converted to ASCII will read `"Met Expectations "`, which does not equal `"Met Expectations"`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great answer but to get your csv back into UTF-8 you can open it in google sheets and then download as a .csv. Then import with trim_ws = T. This will solve the importing problems and won't create any weirdness.